# How to change the text insert after every search in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
class SorguAlani(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(ipadx=100, pady=(10, 0))

        self.rowconfigure(index=(0, 1, 2), weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(index=0,      weight=1)

        self.arama_metni = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.arama_metni.insert(0, "website.com") 
        self.arama_metni.bind("<Return>", lambda _: self.ara_buton_tiklaninca())
        self.arama_metni.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30, pady=(15, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.arama_metni.focus()

        ara_buton = ttk.Button(self, text="Ara", command=lambda: self.ara_buton_tiklaninca())
        ara_buton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, sticky="ew")
        time_interval=1000 #change it as you like

        ayrac = ttk.Separator(self, orient="horizontal")
        ayrac.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(10, 0), padx=30, sticky="ew")

        self.cikti_alani = CiktiAlani(self.parent)

        ara_buton.invoke()


    def ara_buton_tiklaninca(self):
        sorgu = self.arama_metni.get()
        if not sorgu:
            return False

        self.arama_metni.state(["disabled"])
        self.cikti_alani.metin.configure(text="Lütfen Bekleyiniz...", foreground="#EF7F1A")
        self.update()

        ara_buton = ttk.Button(self, text="Ara", command=lambda: self.ara_buton_tiklaninca())
        btk_sorgu = str(BTKSorgu(sorgu))
        
        if "engellenmiştir" not in btk_sorgu:
            self.arama_metni.state(["!disabled", "!invalid"])
            self.cikti_alani.metin.configure(text=btk_sorgu, foreground="#17a2b8")
            Timer(300, ara_buton.invoke).start()
            sk = Skype("", "") # connect to Skype
            ch = sk.chats[""]
            ch.sendMsg("Not banned.")
            
        else:
            self.arama_metni.state(["!disabled", "invalid"])
            self.cikti_alani.metin.configure(text=btk_sorgu, foreground="#dc3545")
            Timer(300, ara_buton.invoke).start()
            sk = Skype("", "") # connect to Skype
            ch = sk.chats[""]
            ch.sendMsg("Banned")

            self.update()
            self.arama_metni.focus()
```

How can i make the program change the "website.com" to "website1.com" after every search and repeat the code? For example after program searches "website.com" i want it to search "website1.com" after that loop it.

I tried some solutions but none of them work.

Comment: I suggest you read up on for loops. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp